# Удаление текста из input по id

Tags: javascript

У меня есть

```
input type="text"
```

c

```
id ="groka"
```

Не пойму как удалить от туда текст пробовал по клику в функции

```
$("#groka").val() == '';
```

Но что-то не робит...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не робит потому что

```
$("#groka").val() == ''
```

есть сравнение значения этого инпута с пустой строкой.
Вам нужно писать так:

```
$("#groka").val('')
```

потому что val() - это и геттер и сеттер значения инпута. Если функция вызывается без аргументов, то вы получаете значение, если с аргументом, то устанавливаете.

Кстати, забавная деталь - типична ошибка, когда вместо оператора равенства пишут оператор присваивания, но не наоборот))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

> $("#groka").val('');